# Gauge covariant derivative on form

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory, differentiation, lie-algebra, yang-mills

Let $e$ be a one-form gauge field that belongs to the adjoint representation of the gauge group, that is SO(1,2). It is defined as 
\begin{equation}
e = e_{\alpha}^{A}T_Adx^{\alpha}.
\end{equation}
The $T_A$ are the generators of the Lie algebra SO(1,2) and obey the usual commutation relations 
\begin{equation}
[T_A,T_B] = -\epsilon_{ABC}T^C,
\end{equation}
with $A,B,C=0,1,2$ and $\epsilon_{012}=1$. The group indices $A,B,C$ are raised and lowered with the flat metric $ \eta_{A,B}=diag(1,-1,-1)$.

The covariant derivative is defined as \begin{equation}
D = d+[e, \quad]\end{equation}

The field strengh is defined in terms of the commutator and it yields 
\begin{equation}
[D_{\alpha},D_{\beta}] = F_{\alpha \beta}^{A}T_{A}
\end{equation}

It is explicity given by

\begin{equation}
F_{\alpha \beta} = \partial_{\alpha}e_{\beta}^{A}-\partial_{\beta}e_{\alpha}^{A}-\epsilon_{BC}^{A}e_{\alpha}^Be_{\beta}^C
\end{equation}

**Question**
I am used to the usual notation in term of coordinates but I am lost here. What shall I put in the commutator ? A random 1-form ? How to explicitely get the last result by evaluating the commutator ?

Comment: The form of $D$ depends on what it acts on. What you wrote is only valid when $D$ acts on one-forms that live in the adjoint representation.

Comment: Thanks @AccidentalFourierTransform, would it be possible for you to write an example on how it act ?

Comment: $D\omega=\mathrm d\omega+[e,\omega]$, where $\omega=\omega^A_\alpha T_A\mathrm dx^\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks again @AccidentalFourierTransform. But then, consider $D_{\beta}w$, is it equal to $dw + [e_{\beta}^AT_Adx^{\beta},w_{\gamma}^BT_Bdx^{\gamma}]$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Lie algebra valued function:

$$e_{\alpha} = e_{\alpha}^AT_A$$
We can write the covariant derivative components

$$D_{\alpha} = \partial_{\alpha} + \mathrm{ad}(e_{\alpha})$$

where, $ \mathrm{ad}(X) = [X, .]$ is the adjoint representation. Please notice that it is linear in the components of $e_{\alpha}$

Thus

$$ \begin{align*}
[D_{\alpha}, D_{\beta}] &= \mathrm{ad}(e_{\alpha}) \partial_{\beta}- \partial_{\beta} \mathrm{ad}(e_{\alpha}) - \mathrm{ad}(e_{\beta}) \partial_{\alpha}+ \partial_{\alpha} \mathrm{ad}(e_{\beta}) +  [\mathrm{ad}(e_{\alpha}) , \mathrm{ad}(e_{\beta}) \\
&= -\mathrm{ad}(\partial_{\beta}e_{\alpha}) + \mathrm{ad}(\partial_{\alpha}e_{\beta}) + \mathrm{ad}([e_{\alpha} , e_{\beta}]) \\
&= \mathrm{ad}(\partial_{\alpha}e_{\beta} -\partial_{\beta}e_{\alpha} + [e_{\alpha} , e_{\beta}]) 
\end{align*}
$$
where the linearity of the adjoint representation of the Lie algebra was used in the application of Leibniz rules and the fact that it is a representation: $[\mathrm{ad}(X), \mathrm{ad}(Y)] = \mathrm{ad} ([X,Y])$

The result is evident from the last expression.

Answer (score 0):

> The covariant derivative is defined as 
>   $$
> \begin{equation}
> D = d+[e, \quad]\end{equation}
> $$
>   What shall I put in the commutator ? A random 1-form ?

For the sake of generosity, let's look at an **n-form** $X$ which transforms covariantly under some gauge transformation $g$
$$
X \rightarrow gXg^{-1}.
$$

The covariant derivative of $X$ should be
\begin{equation}
DX = dX+AX-(-1)^n XA,
\end{equation}
where $A$ is the gauge field 1-form corresponding to the gauge transform $g$ and wedge $\wedge$ product between forms is assumed. **The first $-$ sign in the above expression comes from $g^{-1}$ in $gXg^{-1}$. The second $(-1)^n$ sign has to do with the wedge $\wedge$ product (anti)commuting properties between 1-form $d$ and n-form $X$**.

So for **even(0, 2, ...)-form $X$**, the covariant derivative is
$$
\begin{equation}
DX = dX+[A, X] = dX+AX- XA.
\end{equation}
$$
And for **odd(1, 3, ...)-form $X$**, the covariant derivative is
$$
\begin{equation}
DX = dX+[A, X]_+ = dX+AX+ XA.
\end{equation}
$$

For example, the covariant derivative of the tetrad/vielbein/vierbein **1-form** $e$ is 
$$
T= D_\omega e = de+[w, e]_+  = de + \omega e + e\omega,
$$
where $\omega $ is the spin connection 1-form, which is the gauge field corresponding to the local Lorentz gauge transformation $g_{Lorentz}$. Incidentally, $T$ is the torsion 2-form.

Comment: Hi.  Could you point out where I can see a derivation of the form you have: $$ D_A X = d X + A \wedge X \pm X \wedge A$$